# How to zoom inside a zoomed image?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I am currently working on a Qt application which allows image edition. On the image view, i have to implement a zoom function, which includes the possibility to rezoom on a zoomed image. The user have to select a rectangle zoom on the original image with his mouse, and when he releases, the image view is refreshed with the content of the selection scaled to the dimension of the image view.

My problem is the following : to perform the zoom, i must have the coordinates of the selection in the coordinate system of the original image. This works for the first zooms, but for the followings, the coordinate of the selection are in the coordinate system of the cropped and scaled image, and i can't manage to transform these into coordinates in the coordinate system of the original image.

My first try was to perform this transformation by adding summing the following vectors :
vector_from_top_left_image_to_top_left_second_zoom = vector_from_top_left_image_to_top_left_first_zoom + vector_from_top_left_first_zoom_to_top_left_second_zoom / FACTOR

vector_from_top_left_image_to_bottom_right_second_zoom = vector_from_top_left_image_to_top_left_second_zoom + vector_from_top_left_second_zoom_to_bottom_right_second_zoom / FACTOR

second_zoom_top_left_point = point(vector_from_top_left_image_to_top_left_second_zoom)
second_zoom_bottom_right_point = point(vector_from_top_left_image_to_bottom_right_second_zoom)

But i can't manage to find the value of FACTOR, the result is never satisfying. Could you help me on this, or provide me another idea to solve my problem?